# Неожиданное падение сервера

Tags: nginx, unix, администрирование, php-fpm

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в причинах падения сервера. Образ Ubuntu 16.04.4. Захожу на свой сайт - везде **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. Пытаюсь войти через SSH и SFTP - всё нормально. Иду смотреть логи nginx, а там пусто. Сделал `reboot`, теперь nginx начал отвечать 502 ошибкой. Пошёл опять в логи nginx, а там ошибка:

> connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Сделал:

```
service php7.2-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

И всё заработало. Какие логи смотреть и куда вообще смотреть, чтобы понять, что случилось?

**UPD:** Nginx Amplify показывает, что данные с сервера перестали поступать в 02:00 по GMT +1.

Comment: В какой стране сервер?

Comment: читайте `sudo systemctl status [сервис]` и `sudo journalctl -u [сервис]`

Comment: @Duoxx Франция, OVH.

Comment: если `php-fpm` логи пишет (писал), то какой-нибудь `/var/log/php-fpm/fpm-error.log` смотреть.